# Why is this "the first elliptic curve in nature"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, ho.history-overview, diophantine-equations

The [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/) describes  the elliptic curve [11a3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/11/a/3) (or 11.a3) as "The first elliptic curve in nature". It has minimal Weierstraß equation
$$
y^2 + y = x^3 -  x^2.
$$
My guess is that there is some problem in Diophantus' *Arithmetica*, or perhaps some other ancient geometry problem, that is equivalent to finding a rational point on this curve. What might it be?

---

**Edit:** Here's some extra info that I dug up and only mentioned in the comments. Alexandre Eremenko also mentions this in [an answer below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360867/). The earliest-known example of an elliptic curve is one implicitly considered by Diophantus, in book IV of *Arithmetica*, problem 24 ([Heath's translation](https://archive.org/details/diophantusofalex00heatiala/page/184/mode/1up)): "To divide a given number into two numbers such that their product is cube minus its side". Actually this is a family of curves over the affine line, namely $y(a-y)= x^3-x$, though Diophantus, in his usual way, only provides a single rational point for the single curve corresponding to $a=6$. This curve is [8732.b1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/8732/b/1) in the *L-functions and modular forms database* (the Cremona label is 8732a1). So presumably the comment about 11a3 is not meant to mean "historically first".

Comment: h/t to Anton Hilado for bringing this to my attention [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/anton_hilado/status/1262765452108935168)!

Comment: This text seems to have been written by Nicolas Mascot, if I have interpreted LMFDB correctly; so he might be a good person to ask. https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/ec.q.11.a3.top

Comment: Surely it's because it has smallest conductor. I'm guessing the congruent number curve (for 1, i.e. $y^2=x^3-x$) is the first elliptic curve in history.

Comment: product of two consecutive numbers equals product of three consecutive numbers?

Comment: As far as I know, this is an informal name was coined by John Coates (and, possibly, never in writing). It is one of the three curves of smallest conductor, and has the simplest equation among those.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser Well, Diophantus solved $6y - y^2 = x^3 - x$, as as example of the family $Ay - y^2 = x^3 - x$, or rather "To divide a given number [A] into two numbers such that their product is cube minus its side" ([Problem IV-24](https://archive.org/details/diophantusofalex00heatiala/page/184/mode/1up); thanks to John Baez for pointing me to this)

Comment: This article _Elliptic Curves from Mordell to Diophantus and Back_ by Brown and Myers in Am. Math. Monthly (doi:[10.1080/00029890.2002.11919894](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2002.11919894)) starts with a picture of the curve in my previous comment, labelled "The first elliptic curve".

Comment: FWIW, here is the curve considered by Diophantus: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/8732/b/1

Comment: It is the minimal curve in the isogeny class with the minimal conductor. Though http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/nature.html , which is a very nice source for elliptic curves in nature, puts it as the second and so did Cremona's tables, but it was reordered when it was taken into lmfdb.

Comment: The elliptic curve 11a3 is the curve with smallest Faltings height, which means in basic terms that the period lattice associated to the Néron differential has largest area. I don't know if this is recorded somewhere in the literature, but it can be checked numerically at least.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault yep that is what I meant by "minimal". I believe that John's new way of enumerating curves in isogeny classes is such that the minimal one has label .a1, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser Diophantus treated many more elliptic curves as well (many of his so-called 'double equations' were curves of genus 1 with a natural choice of a rational point). It would be hard to pinpoint any one of them as somehow prior to the others.

Comment: @RP_ oh, interesting!

Comment: If you're interested, I wrote up some things about Diophantus' treatment of (some special cases of) intersections of two quadrics in P^3 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06138 (section 4). Most of it is directly based on the brilliant book of Thomas Heath, only he expressed his findings purely in the language of elementary algebra.

Comment: @liuyao : what you describe seems to be rather the curve https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/37/a/1, in my opinion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked Kevin Buzzard to ask John Coates directly, and it's basically as people have surmised: the moniker is due to the fact the curve appears first in Cremona's book as it has the smallest possible conductor, and it has the smallest coefficients. It is *not* due to historical priority, as Coates knows of 8th/9th century Arabic manuscripts that discuss $y^2 = x^3 - x$, whereas the first occurrence of the "first curve in nature" is apparently a book of Fricke on elliptic functions (I think from 1922, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 24):

I actually only wrote the part that says that this curve is a model for $X_1(11)$, not the first part, which I think was written by John Cremona.

It is standard to order elliptic curves by conductor (e.g. for statistics), and 11 is the smallest possible conductor. However, there are 3 curves with conductor 11, and no canonical way to order them as far as I know (though @François Brunault has an interesting point); for instance LMFDB labels do not order these 3 curves in the same way as Cremona labels.

This curve being the first one could maybe also be understood in terms of modular degree, although this is also ambiguous: if we order them by degree of parametrisation by $X_1(N)$, then this curve, being a model of $X_1(11)$, comes first, but if we order in terms of degree of parametrisation by $X_0(N)$, then [11.a2](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/11/a/2) comes first since it is a model for $X_0(11)$.

Comment: From (nearly) the horse's mouth! Unless Cremona lets us know why, this might be as good as we get (if you can get him to explain, I would be curious to know).

Comment: For each isogeny class of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, one can define a graph (which I believe is canonical) where the vertices are the elliptic curves and the arrows are the étale isogenies of prime degree. Étale means, for example, that the pull-back preserves the Néron differentials. It turns out that this graph is a tree, and the root is the $X_1(N)$-minimal curve (the smallest degree of $X_1(N) \to E$). So there is a unique curve with smallest Faltings height. This last property can fail over number fields.

Comment: PS. I think what I wrote is conditional on Stevens's conjecture on the Manin constant of $X_1(N)$-parametrisations.

Answer (score 16):

I can only echo Tim D's explanation: from Coates via Vlad to me.  I did not know about it having minimal Faltings height.

Comment: But the lmfdb ordering is now deterministic, so there is an answer to why $X_1(11)$ is now the first. I believe to remember that you explained me your criteria for ordering and that it implies that the minimal curve (Falting height, or lattice or ... ) is always the first one. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, the chain of whispers stretches back... I wonder if Coates could be prevailed on to explain? :-)

Answer (score 12):

The closest thing I found in Diophantus is problem IV(24) which is solving the system
$$X_1+X_2=a,\quad X_1X_2=Y^3-Y.$$
Diophantus sets $X_1=x$ and eliminates $X_2$ obtaining
$$x(a-x)=Y^3-Y.$$
This seems to be the first elliptic curve encountered in the book of Diophantus; before that he only considers rational curves and surfaces.

Diophantus choses $a=6$ and obtains a solution $x=26/27,\; Y=17/19$.

(This little research is based on a Russian translation of Diophantus with
comprehensive comments by I. G. Bashmakova, published in Moscow in 1974.)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this curve in the comments to the question; I was going to edit them into the main body tomorrow. I guess (I'm not an algebraic geometer) that your comment is showing that after base change to $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ one can get the Arithmetica IV(24) curve and 11a3 as fibres of the same family of curves over $\mathbb{A}^1$.